# document.createElement() without setting width and height

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, chart.js

In order to avoid the bug in chart.js where hovering over tooltips is overwritting the graph with old ones, I want delete a canvas and create a new one inside a div when i click on a button, this happens in the click function:

```
var chartContainer = document.getElementById('ChartContainer_'+channelName);
var chart = document.getElementById('Chart_'+channelName);
chartContainer.removeChild(chart);

var graph = document.createElement("CANVAS");
graph.setAttribute("id", "Chart_"+channelName);
chartContainer.appendChild(graph);
```

My initial canvas looks like this:

```
<canvas id="Chart_Channel0"></canvas>
```

But if the click function is called it is creating a canvas looking like this:

```
<canvas id="Chart_Channel0" height="187" width="375" 
style="display:block; height: 150px; width:300px;">
```

The canvas is inside of a modal, so the initial canvas seems to fit the size of the modal, but the new one stays too small.

Is it possible to create a canvas without all these parameters?

Comment: The code  you showed (last 3 lines of first snippet) should not add any style attributes to the element. They must be coming from some other source.  You can remove the css inline style width `graph.style.cssText = ""` but because the  styling is likely added after you add the element you will have to poll the element and change it when it gets the nes style settings. BTW don't use `setAttribute` set properties directly `graph.id = "Chart_"+channelName`

Comment: Instead of trying to fix your workaround, why don't you ask a question about the real issue ? (There may even be some duplicates here). This would probably require an [MCVE].